# Set focus to TextBox in a TabItem when the TabItem is selected

Tags: silverlight, focus

I have a Silverlight application that has a TabControl with several TabItems. When the user selects a tab item I want to set the focus to a particular control in that TabItem. How do I do this?

I tried creating an event handler for the TabControl's `SelectionChanged` event and added the following code:

```
private void tcTabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tcTabs != null)
    {
        switch (tcTabs.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: 
                txtTextBox1.Focus();
                break;

            case 1:
                txtTextBox2.Focus();
                break;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Where `txtTextBox1` and `txtTextBox2` are TextBox controls in the tabs in question.

If I set a breakpoint on the `Focus` method calls I see they are being called when I switch from one tab to another, but the control is not focused when the tab displays. My presumption is that I need to call `Focus` at some later point, but I'm at a loss as to when to call it or how.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fun fact of the TabControl: every time you switch tabs, the child control of the TabItem is loaded again. That is, its Loaded event is raised. So you can attach an event there instead.

That said, my preference is to use the Trigger/Action behaviors available in the Expression SDK so I can hook all this up via XAML (to me, it feels more reusable than having to attach events every time I need this).

Add a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll if you don't already have one.

Use this trigger action subclass:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace SilverlightApplication1 {
    public class SetFocusAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject> {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "Target", typeof( Control ), typeof( SetFocusAction ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

        public Control Target {
            get { return (Control) GetValue( TargetProperty ); }
            set { SetValue( TargetProperty, value ); }
        }

        protected override void Invoke( object parameter ) {
            if( Target != null ) {
                Target.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And hook it up like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <sdk:TabControl>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                <Grid>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                            <local:SetFocusAction Target="{Binding ElementName=tb1}"></local:SetFocusAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="30" x:Name="tb1"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                <Grid>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                            <local:SetFocusAction Target="{Binding ElementName=tb2}"></local:SetFocusAction>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="30" x:Name="tb2"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note that when you first run an app with this in it the Silverlight object itself may not have focus, so you'd have to hook up javascript to focus on it manually. But once the user clicks in the Silverlight app (or your javascript sets focus) this action will do its job.

And for fun, here's a full Behavior subclass that will work with a DataForm and should work on other templated controls.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SilverlightApplication1 {
    public class SetFocusBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement> {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register( "TargetName", typeof( string ), typeof( SetFocusBehavior ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

        private bool _setFocusOnLayoutUpdated;

        public string TargetName {
            get { return (string) GetValue( TargetNameProperty ); }
            set { SetValue( TargetNameProperty, value ); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached() {
            base.OnAttached();

            this.AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler( AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated );
            this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler( AssociatedObject_Loaded );
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching() {
            base.OnDetaching();

            this.AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated -= new EventHandler( AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated );
            this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler( AssociatedObject_Loaded );
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
            if( !FindAndSetFocus() ) {
                _setFocusOnLayoutUpdated = true;
            }
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_LayoutUpdated( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            if( _setFocusOnLayoutUpdated ) {
                _setFocusOnLayoutUpdated = false;
                FindAndSetFocus();
            }
        }

        private bool FindAndSetFocus() {
            var found = Find( this.AssociatedObject ) as Control;
            if( found != null ) {
                found.Focus();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private DependencyObject Find( DependencyObject root ) {
            if( root != null ) {
                if( (string) root.GetValue( FrameworkElement.NameProperty ) == TargetName ) {
                    return root;
                }

                for( int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( root ); i++ ) {
                    var result = Find( VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( root, i ) );
                    if( result != null )
                        return result;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <sdk:TabControl>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                <Grid>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:SetFocusBehavior TargetName="tb1"></local:SetFocusBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBox Width="200" Height="30" x:Name="tb1"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                <Grid>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:SetFocusBehavior TargetName="tb2"></local:SetFocusBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <tk:DataForm CurrentItem="sometext">
                        <tk:DataForm.EditTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Width="200" Height="30" x:Name="tb2"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </tk:DataForm.EditTemplate>
                    </tk:DataForm>
                </Grid>
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer and code snippet. This works great for controls "directly" in the TabItem, but in some TabItems I need to set the focus to a TextBox within a DataForm. I can do this programmatically using `DataFormID.FindNameInContent`, but is there a way to get this sort of functionality baked into the trigger?

Comment: All templated controls (like the DataForm) are going to give you issue. You can change the action to use the VisualTreeHelper to recursively search for the given name, however the templates aren't necessarily going to be ready by Loaded, so you have to hook up to LayoutUpdated (and be sure you're only doing it once per Loaded event call).

Comment: I'm having a problem getting this to work when I am adding the TabItem programmatically as shown below. Once the TabItem is in place I can switch to another tab and when I come back, the behavior works but it does not work when it is first added. Any ideas @AdamSills ?
`var tabItem = new TabItem { Content = new MyViewUserControl, Header = MyTabHeaderUserControl };
mainTabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
mainTabControl.SelectedItem = tabItem;`

Comment: @AdamSills I eventually found a solution to my problem. My view is binding to ViewModel data that is being loaded asnychronously by WCF RIA Services. If I delay the call to `Control.Focus()` until after the service call completes, then the TextBox ends up with the focus as required. 

FYI, I implemented this solution using a custom `TriggerAction` as the earlier part of your answer suggests so I could use a `PropertyChangedTrigger` against my ViewModel.IsEditorReady property. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: "every time you switch tabs, the child control(s) of the TabItem are loaded again. That is, their Loaded event is raised" That was what I needed, many thanks.